# Guías de estilo oficiales para HTML, CSS y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Según la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estilo_de_programaci%C3%B3n), el estilo de programación es:

> Estilo de programación (también llamado estándares de código o convención de código) es un término que describe convenciones para escribir código fuente en ciertos lenguajes de programación.
>
> El estilo de programación es frecuentemente dependiente del lenguaje de programación que se haya elegido para escribir. Por ejemplo el estilo del lenguaje de programación C variará con respecto al del lenguaje BASIC.

En varios lenguajes existen guias de estilo que podríamos llamar "oficiales" como en el caso de PHP y Python, aunque son una recomendación, no un estándar obligatorio:

- PHP: [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)
- Python: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

En HTML, CSS y JS utilizo las guías de estilo de Google:

[HTML/CSS Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml)

[JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml)

Mi pregunta es:

¿Existen otras guías de estilo más reconocidas u "oficiales" para HTML, CSS y JS?

Comment: Estoy bastante seguro que [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) sería el estandard en esto.

Comment: No sólo puedes tener estilos por lenguaje sino por frameworks, cada uno puede generar guías de estilo diferentes.

Comment: Pues supongo que "oficial" sería la de la w3c https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/ , solo da unas pautas bastante generales aunque luego tenemos las especificaciones, pautas de accesibilidad, etc que también nos dicen como escribir el código.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/Firefox/Edici%C3%B3n_de_Desarrollador) de Mozilla es un gran referente, por no decir el que mas apoyos recibe, un proyecto solido y con seguimiento continuo.

Comment: @Shaz difícil entender a los moderadores u administradores la pregunta se trata de opiniones e sugerencias y es aceptada sin embargo otras preguntas que se basa a lo mismo es rechaza o peor aún mencionan que esperas que escriba el código por ti estos es decepcionante se necesita dar una recompenza al parecer para que una pregunta que no se basa a las politicas o el uso del sitio. Más de uno menciono que el sitio es para ayudar en errores que se presenten.

Comment: @J.Doe en este caso mi problema es que no sabía (no sé) si existen guías de estilo de código oficiales o reconocidas, no estoy pidiendo opiniones sobre cuál es mejor o cuál prefieren.

Comment: @Shaz Ok entiendo con lo dicho no es que no este de acuerdo, pero la intriga es que muchas preguntas son cerradas por no poseer código cómo un problema, en ocaciones son similares a su pregunta y son cerradas o puesto en espera lo justo de aquellas preguntas que se esperen tres días para así el usuario observando que no tiene reapuesta pueda iniciar con una recompenza. Las reglas no se aplican para todos una pregunta que no se rechace alparecer se incia con recompenzas.

Comment: @J.Doe dices que "muchas preguntas son cerradas por no poseer código cómo un problema" pero resulta que esas preguntas por lo general son del formato "Tengo problema con `<funcionalidad>`. ¿Cómo lo hago?" o "Me sale un error al hacer `<foo>`. Ayuda." o también "Necesito que mi programa pueda hacer `<bar>`. ¿Sugerencias?". Son cerradas principalmente por no demostrar un esfuerzo para resolver el problema. Un ejemplo de pregunta que no necesita código es [esta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21707/227) y que fue mal cerrada.

Comment: Esta pregunta no se ajusta bien al formato del sitio: aunque es específica, se basa principalmente en opiniones y todas las preguntas puede ser igualmente válidas. Es un caso similar al de la pregunta sobre IA: una pregunta que debería estar cerrada pero que no se acabará cerrando nunca porque tiene tantas visitas y votos positivos que siempre habrá quien (en mi opinión, equivocadamente) la acabe reabriendo.

Comment: @ArtEze Si no estoy mal esta pregunta ya a tenido ya algunas recompensas y con una respuesta ya aceptada y con varias preguntas muy buenas no entiendo que más fondo se puede llegar a mi me parece muy completa las respuestas.

Comment: @J.Doe Me gustaría que se hable un poco más del ECMA-262, pero es cierto, están bastante bien.

Comment: @ArtEze Hubiese sido mucho mejor que se cree una nueva pregunta basada en ese tema más aún con aquella recompensa se obtendrá muchas respuesta basadas a solo a ese tema.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

El propósito de las guías es ayudar a lidiar con la [Ley de la trivialidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_de_Parkinson_de_la_trivialidad), también conocida en el desarrollo de software como el *efecto de la caseta de bicis*.

Algunas de estas son requeridas si intentas contribuir de alguna forma en algunos repositorios y librerías publicas (ej [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/latest/dev/making-changes.html)). Todo esto ayuda a que el código sea fácil de mantener aunque sea escrito por múltiples desarrolladores (incluso aunque no tengan contacto entre sí).

> Todo el código de cualquier fuente debería parecer escrito por una sola persona sin importar cuantos han contibuido

Otra de las razones de dichas guías es ayudar a lidiar con la algunas de las rarezas de los lenguajes.

Muchas de ellas comparten similitudes como el uso de `var` al principio de las funciones para evitar [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) y no usar el `eval`.

Voy a mencionar las más notables para JavaScript.

[**Guía de Crockford**](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)

Este es un personaje muy conocido del mundo de los navegadores, entre otras cosas por haber inventado [JSON](http://json.org/) y haber escrito un libro ["JavaScript, the good parts"](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748/). Las reglas más notables son

*Uso del operador ternario en líneas diferentes*

```
condicion1 && condicion2
    ? expresión
    : expresión
```

*Uso de la expresión de retorno en la misma línea para evitar la inserción del punto y coma automático.*

```
// Recomendado
return expresion;

return {
    propiedad: 'valor'
};

// No recomendado
// Se convierte en return; lo que resulta en undefined
return
{
     propiedad: 'valor'
}
```

[**Guía de jQuery**](https://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)

*Uso de corchetes en bloques*

```
if/else/for/while/try
```

Siempre usan corchetes `{}` y siempre van en múltiples líneas

```
if (true) 
    alert();
```

se transforma en

```
if (true) {
    alert();
}
```

*Operadores unarios*

Los operadores unarios (ej., !, ++) no deben tener espacios con respecto a su operador

```
// No recomendado

a ++;

(! a)
```

[**Guía de npm**](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style)

*No usan puntos y comas `;` salvo contadas ocasiones*

Ciclos `for(;;)`. Son requeridos por el lenguaje.

Ciclos nulos `while (condición);` (Obviamente no recomendado).

Instrucción `case` en una misma línea que el break `case 'valor': hazAlgo(); break`

En frente de un paréntesis `(` o corchete `[` al inicio de la línea. Esto evita que la expresión sea interpretada como una llamada a función o un acceso a una propiedad respectivamente.

Ejemplo

```
;(x || y).doSomething()
;[a, b, c].forEach(doSomething)
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
  switch (state) {
    case 'begin': start(); continue
    case 'end': finish(); break
    default: throw new Error('unknown state')
  }
  end()
}
```

*Coma al principio*

Divide una expresión larga en sus comas y pon las comas al principio

```
var magicWords = [ 'abracadabra'
                 , 'gesundheit'
                 , 'ventrilo'
                 ]
  , spells = { 'fireball' : function () { setOnFire() }
             , 'water' : function () { putOut() }
             }
  , a = 1
  , b = 'abc'
  , etc
  , somethingElse
```

[**Guía JavaScript Standard**](https://github.com/feross/standard)

*Usa un solo var por línea*

```
// Recomendado
var a;
var b;
// No recomendado
var a, b;
```

*Siempre usa window*

```
 // No recomendado
alert();
// Recomendado
window.alert();
```

[**Guía de estilo de node**](https://github.com/felixge/node-style-guide)

*Usa return para reducir código*

```
// Recomendado
function isPercentage(val) {
  if (val < 0) {
    return false;
  }

  if (val > 100) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

// No recomendado
function isPercentage(val) {
  if (val >= 0) {
    if (val < 100) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

*No crees funciones dentro de funciones para evitar el anidamiento a menos que sea estrictamente necesario*

```
// Recomendado
setTimeout(function() {
  client.connect(afterConnect);
}, 1000);

function afterConnect() {
  console.log('winning');
}

//No recomendado
setTimeout(function() {
  client.connect(function() {
    console.log('losing');
  });
}, 1000);
```

[**Guía de airbnb**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript)

Esta viene con detalles adicionales para lenguajes y frameworks como [SASS](https://github.com/airbnb/css#sass), [ES6](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#ecmascript-6-es-2015-styles) y [React](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react)

Usa destructuración para acceder a las propiedades de los objetos cuando quieres asignarlas a variables.

```
// No recomendado
function getFullName(user) {
  const firstName = user.firstName;
  const lastName = user.lastName;

  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

// Recomendado
function getFullName(user) {
  const { firstName, lastName } = user;
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}

// La mejor variante posible
function getFullName({ firstName, lastName }) {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`;
}
```

Siempre usa clases en lugar de manipular el prototipo directamente

```
// No recomendado
function Queue(contents = []) {
  this.queue = [...contents];
}
Queue.prototype.pop = function () {
  const value = this.queue[0];
  this.queue.splice(0, 1);
  return value;
};


// Recomendado
class Queue {
  constructor(contents = []) {
    this.queue = [...contents];
  }
  pop() {
    const value = this.queue[0];
    this.queue.splice(0, 1);
    return value;
  }
}
```

[**Idiomatic**](https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/)

Las instrucciones `const` y `let` deberían aparecer al inicio de su bloque

```
// No recomendado
function foo() {
  let foo,
    bar;
  if ( condition ) {
    bar = "";
    // statements
  }
}
// Recomendado
function foo() {
  let foo;
  if ( condition ) {
    let bar = "";
    // statements
  }
}
```

Usa [truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) para comprobar tamaños de los arreglos y cadenas de caracteres

```
// No recomendado
if ( array.length > 0 ) 
if ( array.length === 0 )
if ( string !== "" ) 
if ( string === "" )

// Recomendado
if ( array.length ) 
if ( !array.length )
if ( string ) 
if ( !string )
```

Estoy seguro que hay más y con el tiempo pueden seguir surgiendo. Cada framework JavaScript puede crear su estilo también por lo que puedes terminar con estilos combinados.

Para CSS puedes consultar

https://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/

http://codeguide.co/#css

https://github.com/ThinkUpLLC/ThinkUp/wiki/Code-Style-Guide:-CSS

http://primercss.io/guidelines/

https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/css/

Recuerda también que puedes escoger no trabajar con CSS, sino con algún lenguaje preprocesador como [Sass](https://sass-lang.com), [Less](http://lesscss.org) y [Compass](http://compass-style.org) que pueden a su vez pueden tener guías de estilo.

Concluyendo, si tienes en consideración la gran cantidad de variantes que existen la solución es que **decidas tu propio estilo**. Escoge una de las guías y síguela, si te parece que no se ajusta a lo que quieres cambia a otra o hazle pequeñas modificaciones a tu gusto. Lo importante es que tu y los otros que escriban código contigo estén de acuerdo con un estándar y este sea visible a los nuevos desarrolladores.

Te dejo una cita de la guía de node

> Una guía para estilar tu código JavaScript/ node.js. Bifurca y ajusta a tu gusto.

Comment: @devconcept difícil entender a los moderadores u administradores la pregunta se trata de opiniones e sugerencias y es aceptada sin embargo otras preguntas que se basa a lo mismo es rechaza o peor aún mencionan que esperas que escriba el código por ti estos es decepcionante se necesita dar una recompenza al parecer para que una pregunta que no se basa a las politicas o el uso del sitio. Más de uno menciono que el sitio es para ayudar en errores que se presenten.

Comment: @J.Doe Tienes razón con que la pregunta puede ser basada en opiniones pero es un tema que interesa a muchos. Mi respuesta no se limita a mencionar guías sino a tratar el problema subyacente. La solución a la ley de trivialidad es zanjar la discusión (muchos jefes de equipo entienden esto). Si no puedes convencer de tu punto de vista usa un estándar reconocido. La razón por la que menciono las diferentes guías es porque para contribuir a algunos repositorios Open Source **debes** conocer de la existencia de ellas de lo contrario los pull-request serán rechazados aunque el código esté bien.

Comment: @devconcept yo entiendo igual no estoy en contra pero si la ley se aplica para uno pues que sea para todos es lo más justo. Ejemplo mi pregunta se a rechazado tres veces y cerrada sin poder esperar los dos días para iniciar una recompenza. Adicional aquello mi pregunta puede ser de interes un sistema de tags que funciona correctamente muchos les gustaria tener un sistema de tag es un tema de interes solo por querer mejorar el sistema no es aceptada.

Answer (score 11):

te diría que uses las guías de esta página (aunque están en inglés) http://www.w3schools.com para HTML y CSS, suelo utilizarlas cuando tengo alguna duda o no me acuerdo de alguna propiedad y van genial. Para Javascript suelo usar https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript que si bien es de un navegador, la encuentro bastante completita. De todas formas, w3schools también te sirve para Javascript, tiene un apartado para ello (y para otras cosillas también). La de mozilla también tiene una sección para HTML y CSS dividida en 3 niveles, este sería el enlace: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Tutoriales y eliges el nivel (aunque no suelo mirar esta para HTML y CSS, prefiero w3school).

Claro que después, depende de los frameworks etc que utilices, quizás algunas cosas de las guías no te sirvan de mucho, pero en esos casos sería buscar la guía de ese framework en cuestión.

Luego, si esas páginas no me sirven o no me entero mucho de que dicen, suelo buscar por foros o por páginas web explicativas como puede ser http://www.aulaclic.es/index.htm o http://librosweb.es/   . La última suele traducir las guías oficiales de otras cosas como Bootstrap 3 (framework) a español.

Answer (score 10):

Con una búsqueda rápida a través de tu buscador de confianza puedes encontrar lineamientos para [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp), [CSS](http://cssguidelin.es/) y [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) como por ejemplo:

Para el caso particular de JavaScript te recomienda que revises el estándar de [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) el cual da la especificación propia del lenguaje y utilices la herramienta [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) para una correcta codificación.

Comment: w3Schools es popular pero no es oficial. Según entiendo ECMAScript incluye guías de estilo ya que se trata de la especificación del lenguaje, como lo mencionas. JSLint como tal es una herramienta pero detrás de esta debería haber algo que fundamente como opera, eso podría ser una guía de estilo.

Answer (score 10):

> Guía de estilo para **HTML**, **CSS** y **Javascript.**

Pues no hay nada mejor que las fuentes oficiales:

- Fuente oficial **HTML** [w3](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/).
- Fuente oficial **CSS** [w3](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/).
- Una guía completa basada a la pagina oficial [w3](https://www.w3.org/) con muchos ejemplos html, css, javascript y jQuery es [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) todos los ejemplos son sencillos originales sin nigun tipo de complementos u **plugin.**
- Fuente oficial de javascript seguramente es le herencia de jQuery en su documentación se encuentran muchos ejemplos https://jquery.com/ hasta de como crear tu propio plugin

Existen otros sitios adicionales con muy buenos estilos y una guia completa paso a paso:

- http://librosweb.es/
- tutoriales entre otros en el mismo [sitio](http://librosweb.es/tutorial/como-evitar-que-tus-archivos-javascript-y-css-sean-manipulados/)

> Para mi la mejor guía completa en estilos tanto para html, css, y javascript es [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) en **w3schools** existen muchos ejemplos sencillos avanzados y muy prácticos.

Answer (score 10):

Una de las guías de estilo para **JavaScript** que más y mejor acogida está teniendo es la del equipo de desarrollo de [**Airbnb**](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). Está muy bien documentada y consta de numerosos ejemplos. En ese repo también encontrarás una guía para [CSS-in-JavaScript](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/css-in-javascript) y otra para [CSS & Sass](https://github.com/airbnb/css) que están muy bien.

Answer (score 5):

Existe un organismo encargado de actualizar y crear nuevos estándares web: el llamado **W3C** o **WORLD WIDE WEB Consortium**.

`W3Schools` es un popular sitio web para el aprendizaje de tecnologías web en línea podrás encontrar el estándar `HTML` `CSS` `JavaScript` y algun lenguaje más de programación. No está afiliado con el `W3C`.

Podrás encontrar varios temarios sobre cada lenguaje, los más útiles: Tutoriales, Ejemplos y Referencias.

### En primer lugar, veamos el estándar `HTML`

> Estándar **HTML**:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Aquí te explican detalladamente cada etiqueta `HTML`.

Etiquetas `HTML` ordenadas alfabéticamente

> Referencia de etiquetas **HTML**:
>   http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp

Podrás también validar tu web en `W3C`, para así comprobar si tu web cumple con los estándares `HTML`.

- http://validator.w3.org/

### Ejemplos para estándar `CSS`

> Estándar **CSS**
>   http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Podrás encontrar todos los ejemplos necesarios para añadir estilos `CSS` a nuestras web.

> Referencia de **CSS**
>   http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp

Podrás también validar tu `CSS`, para comprobar si cumple con los estándares.

- https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/?ucn_task=full-css&ucn_lang=es

### Ejemplos para estándar `JavaScript`

> Estándar **JavaScript**
>   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp

Esta página contiene algunos ejemplos de lo que `JavaScript` puede hacer.

**JavaScript** y **HTML DOM** referencia:

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp

`JQuery` es una biblioteca `JavaScript`.

> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

### Otros Ejemplos:

Tambien te dejo un página de `W3Schools` con grandes ejemplos utilizando `HTML`, `CSS`, `JavaScript` y `jQuery` (Ejemplos como Slideshow, Modal login, ..., Progress Bars, etc.):

- http://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp

Guía de `JavaScript`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 4):

Ya que hay excelentes respuestas con explicaciones. Me limitaré a citar algunas de las guías de estilo más usadas y/o conocidas actualmente, ofreciendo los enlaces a cada una de ellas:

## HTML/CSS

1. [Primer de Github](http://primercss.io)
2. [Google CSS/HTML Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html)
3. [Idiomatic CSS](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css)
4. [CSS Guidelin](http://cssguidelin.es)
5. [ThinkUp](https://github.com/ThinkUpLLC/ThinkUp/wiki/Code-Style-Guide:-CSS)
6. [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/css/)
7. [CodeGuide](http://codeguide.co)
8. [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp)
9. jQueryFoundation: [HTML](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/html/) y [CSS](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/css/)
10. Mozilla [HTML en General](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) / [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) / [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

## Javascript

1. [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html)
2. [jQuery Foundation](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)
3. [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)
4. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)
5. [Javascript.com](https://www.javascript.com/learn/javascript/strings)
6. [WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/javascript/)
7. [Standard.js](https://standardjs.com)
8. [Hapijs](https://hapijs.com/styleguide)
9. [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/javascript/javascript-coding-standards)
10. [Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Javascript/Coding_Style)

Espero que este 10 + 10 sea útil.