# DESCARGAR SOFTWARE CON LICENCIA

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes, necesito descargar HTML5 y Javascript para windows 7 64 bits. Agradezco si alguien podría regalarme una pagina o link de descarga.

Comment: Ese "software" viene embebido en los navegadores

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es un servidor web, puedes usar xampp o wamp

Comment: Cristian, Html y javascript son tecnologias que son interpretadas por los navegadores. Te recomiendo que veas un [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqMfPS8jPys) para que te familiarices.

Comment: Como  alternativa a lo que propone @Ruben , sería bueno revisar [está pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22406/gu%C3%ADas-de-estilo-oficiales-para-html-css-y-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Mira Cristian, debes familiarizarte antes con lenguajes de programación

Un lenguaje de programación es la base de todo software, son los que construyen los programas, por eso no se descargan, consulta un poco sobre lengueges actuales de programación y su funcionalidad en este bello mundo que es la informatica.

Te deseo suerte y no te desanimes.

Saludos

Te dejo unos links para que te orientes un poco

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n

http://noticias.universia.com.ar/consejos-profesionales/noticia/2016/02/22/1136443/conoce-cuales-lenguajes-programacion-populares.html

http://es.ccm.net/contents/304-lenguajes-de-programacion

Comment: Excelente Alejo. Siento que fueron muy rudos al dar tantos puntos negativos. Se supone que este sitio es para cuidarnos las espaldas entre nosotros y esa no es la manera.

Comment: Lo senti de la misma forma, a veces somos muy rudos con esto, pero bueno, todos venimos de abajo...no?

de acuerdo con vos.. Einer.. 

Espero que Cristian pueda aprender mas

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

Lee [Primeros pasos en la web](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web)

## Explicación

HTML5 y JavaScript, junto a CSS, son usados para escribir código para páginas y aplicaciones web. En sí mismos no son software para ser instalado, son lenguajes, uno de marcado de texto y el otro de programación.

Answer (score -2):

Para programar página web del lado del cliente (La parte visual), no necesitas muchas cosas, a lo mucho un editor de código (Visual Studio Code). Supongo que ya usa un tutorial para aprender

Pero si vas a hacer código para el servidor, necesitas montar un servidor casero, hay un programa que te instala uno llamado (XAMPP) para hacer las pruebas del código PHP en el servidor, para poder crear una base de datos entra a la pagina del servidor casero: Localhost/phpmyadmin/