# Cómo funcionan las variables en blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Ttengo una tabla llamada comentarios, la cual debe devolver una lista de comentarios de los usuarios.

Para eso, tengo escrito lo siguiente en el fichero ComentarioController:

```
class ComentarioController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $com= Comentario::all();
        return view('comentarios.index', compact('comentarios'));
    }
}
```

Esta vista tiene la siguiente referencia en el fichero web.php:

```
Route::get('/comentarios','ComentarioController@index');
```

Y ahora me voy a \resources\views\comentarios y escribo lo siguiente en index.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Todos los comentarios") }} </h1>
@forelse($com as $c)
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<h2> Código de la planta: {{ $c->planta }} </h2>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
{{ $c->comentario }}
</div>
</div>
@empty
<div class="alert alert-danger">
{{ __("No hay ningún comentario sobre plantas en este momento") }}
</div>
@endforelse
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Pero al ejecutar la vista, me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si omito todo lo que use la variable $c, puedo ver la vista, por lo que claramente el problema está en que no se detecta la variable $com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente no estás pasando la variable `$com` a la vista, solo estás pasando una variable `$comentarios` que no está definida en lo que muestras, de nuevo, no olvides aplicar el estilo de código PSR-2:

```
class ComentarioController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $com = Comentario::all();
        return view('comentarios.index', compact('com'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues gracias, asi que era el compact. Sinceramente, no entiendo a que te refieres con el codigo PSR-2. ¿Me lo puedes aclarar, por favor?

Comment: Este es el enlace oficial: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: En ingles, aunque alcanzo a entender que es un sistema para ordenar el código y que sea legible, lo cual me imagino que en el caso de index.blade.php va a ser no. A ver si para futuras peticiones de ayuda aprendo a tener el codigo mejor ordenado.

Comment: Es la guía de estilo "oficial" de PHP, aplica para la parte de "backend" normalmente, en este caso todas las clases. No aplica para blade, pues es un sistema de templating.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez Respecto a lo del psr-2 que te comenta Shaz puedes echarle un vistazo a esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119811/guia-de-estilo-y-buenas-practicas-php/119812#119812