# Como conectar y mostrar datos de una base de datos en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero conectar una base de datos a una página PHP, en otra que tengo me anda bien, pero es esta necesito conectar y mostrar adentro del echo.
Tengo esto que uso en otra página:

```html
<?php 

 $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','user','mypass','mibase');

 ?>
 
 //Esto lo pongo arriba de la etiqueta <html>
 
<?php 
  $sql="SELECT * from dpartidos";
  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>

// Y para mostralo lo hago así

<li><?php echo $mostrar['dia1'] ?></li>

//Pero necesito ponerlo acá:

//...PHP

if ($quediaes=="Tue" && 11 <= $hora && $hora <= 12 ) {

 $sql="SELECT * from dpartidos";
 $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

 while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<center>
<h3>Ahora EN VIVO: 
  <a href="#" 
     onclick="window.open( \'https://paginas.com\', \'_self\');
              window.open( \'https://paginas.com\', \'_blank\');" >' . $mostrar['autor'] . '</a>     
</h3>
</center>';

else if ($quediaes=="Tue" && 15 <= $hora && $hora <= 16 ) {
echo '<center>
<h3>Ahora EN VIVO: 
  <a href="#" 
     onclick="window.open( \'https://www.\', \'_self\');
              window.open( \'https://www.\', \'_blank\');" >
  UN PARTIDO - 
  </a>
  <a href="#" 
     onclick="window.open( \'https://www.\', \'_self\');
              window.open( \'https://www.\', \'_blank\');" >
  UN PARTIDO
  </a>      
</h3>
</center>';
}
}
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Lo usual en estos casos es mandar a  ejecutar el código que consulta a la base de datos desde el segundo archivo mediante Ajax, recoger la respuesta del servidor y mostrarla en el DOM de ese archivo. Lo que intentas hacer es *extraño*, complicado y poco usual. Existen herramientas como Ajax para hacer ese tipo de operaciones con suma facilidad y de forma totalmente transparente al usuario, sin tener que estar abriendo ventanas suplementarias. Las ventanas suplementarias, los modales, los popup, son elementos del siglo pasado que convendría evitar.

Comment: No entiendo nada de lo que dijiste jaja.
Algo así no se puede hacer, por lo menos cerrar el php y volver abrir ahí?

Comment: *¿Algo así no se puede hacer, por lo menos cerrar el php y volver abrir ahí?*  Sí, se puede hacer, pero eso supondría una **pésima experiencia de usuario**, no es lo mismo que yo tenga todo en mi ventana actual, a manera de escritorio, donde consulto lo que quiera y me lo presente en la misma ventana donde estoy a que me abra una o varias ventanas más para mostrarme ciertos datos. Lo que quiero decir es que con Ajax tú puedes cambiar lo que sea de la página actual sin necesidad de moverte de ella, o sea, hacerla totalmente interactiva con el servidor.

Comment: Pero tenes algo, un ejemplo, un tutorial o algo para ayudar en vez de comentar sin responder la pregunta?
Porque no entiendo tus respuestas...

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo completo de lo que digo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/6fju-td04). Es muy parecido a lo que quieres. Desde una única página se envía un id al servidor mediante Ajax, para que busque a los actores en la base de datos en base a ese id que se envió. El servidor responde con los datos y llena los campos del formulario. Si por ejemplo tú quieres ver el autor con id `2`, escribes ese id en el campo de búsqueda, das click al botón y te actualiza el formulario con los nuevos datos, y así sucesivamente. Del mismo modo que haces eso, puedes traer varias filas para mostrarlas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que aprender a concatenar o el uso de las comillas dobles.

Para [concatenar en PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php) se utiliza el punto, ejemplo:

```
$variable = 'una variable';
echo 'texto concatenado con ' . $variable . ' en un echo';
// resultado
// texto concatenado con una variable en un echo
```

También en php cuando utilizamos comillas dobles las variables php son expandidas, ejemplo:

```
$variable = 'una variable';
echo "texto concatenado con $variable en un echo";
// resultado
// texto concatenado con una variable en un echo
```

Aquí puedes consultar la [documentación sobre cadenas de caracteres](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php).

Por lo tanto tu código podría quedar algo así:

```
echo '<center>
    <h3>Ahora EN VIVO: 
      <a href="#" 
         onclick="window.open( \'https://paginas.com\', \'_self\');
                  window.open( \'https://paginas.com\', \'_blank\');" >' . $mostrar['dia1'] . '</a>     
    </h3>
    </center>';
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probé y me sale: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF)

En una linea nada que ver con lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: En el código que pusiste no hay ningun `if`, `elseif`

Comment: Ahí edite el tema, el error está en ese " Else if"

Comment: @MatiPHP Revisa la documentacion, no puedes utilizar un `elseif` si no forma parte de un `if`. Debes entender que `elseif` extiende una sentencia `if` pero por si solo no es valido. http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: Tambien te recomendaria que le eches un vistazo a esto: [Guia de estilo y buenas practicas PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119811/guia-de-estilo-y-buenas-practicas-php) para que trates de hacer tu codigo mas legible y facil de entender.

Comment: Ahí edite el codigo, asi lo tengo realmente. Puse "//...PHP" porque antes de eso tengo las variables que no vienen al tema por si no entendes.

Comment: @MatiPHP Te falta una llave de cierre `}` en el `if`, has editado tanto la pregunta que la respuesta ya a quedado casi descontextualizada. Deberias de ser capaz de ver los errores de sintaxsis, es mas facil si indentas tu codigo adecuadamente. un saludo.

Comment: Ese } se cierra al final...
Se agradece la ayuda, pero creo que no entendiste, espero que alguien si entienda y pueda ayudarme. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: @MatiPHP NO. Debes cerrar el if antes de poder iniciar un elseif. Revise la documentacion, como le indique: http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.elseif.php - la estuctuara debe ser: `if ($expr) {}
elseif ($expr) {} 
else {}`. Deberia revisar su codigo y indentarlo adecuadamente, entremezcla estructuras de control sin sentido en lo que muestra, tambien el while esta mal. Siento que no quieras entenderlo, ni hacer el esfuerzo de leer la docuemtacion al menos. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdón, te pido mil disculpas, tenes razón, fue un error mio, ya está funcionando, de verdad, fue un error mio.
Anda bien lo que me pasaste, voy a leer eso de que mi codigo sea mas legible. Te pido de nuevo perdon.