# Ingresar el parámetro de un método desde el interior de otro

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

La cuestión es que no sé como puedo ingresar en el método ValidateUser() el resultado que me trajo la consulta a la base de datos realizado en el método SendAction(). Adjunto código del archivo validar.php:

```
<?php

include_once("conexion.php");

class validacion extends Conn
{

private $conexion;

function __construct()
{
    $this->conexion = new Conn();
}

public function SendAction($usuario, $pass){

    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE username =  :username  AND password = :password";

    $consulta = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);

    $consulta->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $consulta->bindParam(":password", $pass);

    $consulta->execute();

    ValidateUser($consulta);
}

public function ValidateUser($consulta){

    $count = $consulta->rowCount();

    if($count){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = true;
        header('Location:index2.php');  
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "El usuario o contraseña no coincide"; 
    }
    echo $count;
}

public function nullValue(){

    echo '<script>alert("No puedes ingresar valores nulos");</script>';

}

public function CerrarSesion(){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = false;
    header('Location:index.php');
    exit();
}

}

?>
```

Código del archivo validacion.php:

```
<?php

//Incluimos la conexión
include_once("conexion.php");

//Incluimos el archivo con las funciones
include("validar.php");

//Creamos el objeto de la Clase Validacion
$prueba = new Validacion();

//Creamos el objeto de la conexión a la Base de Datos
$conexion = new Conn();

//Validamos el envio del formulario
if(isset($_POST['enviado'])){

    //Guardamos los valores de los campos en variables
    $usuario = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    //Validamos si alguno de los campos se encuentra vacío
    if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass)){

    //Llamamos el método nullValue() en caso de que algún campo se encuentre vacío
        $prueba->nullValue();

    }else{

        /*Inyectamos los parámetros requeridos para realizar el método SendAction() de la clase Validacion*/
        $prueba->SendAction($usuario,$pass);

        //Llamamos el método ValidateUser() para que valide la existencia del usuario
        $prueba->ValidateUser();

        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['cerrarSesion'])){

        //Cerramos la sesión
        $prueba->CerrarSesion();

}

?>
```

Comment: Deberías utilizar la variable reservada `$this`, es decir `$this->ValidateUser($consulta);` . Como recomendación los nombres de clase se declaran en `StudlyCaps` y los nombres de los métodos se declaran en `camelCase`. Puedes echarle un vistazo a la gia de estilo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119811/guia-de-estilo-y-buenas-practicas-php

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @Xerif, tu código es *incoherente*, pues dentro de la clase habría una llamada a `ValidateUser` desde el método `SendAction`, y también en el programa, llamas 1º a `SendAction` y luego a `ValidateUser` ¿? Haciendo eso, se estaría validando dos veces la misma información de forma innecesaria. Me parece que vas camino a montar un lío en el código, por lo que deberías planificar bien tu clase, construyéndola de una forma coherente.